# Could Not Load File Or Assembly for DevExpress Xtrareport in lightswitch

Tags: silverlight, devexpress, visual-studio-lightswitch, xtrareport

i encountered this strange error when i tried to move my lightswitch project from my work laptop to another exact pc everything was working fine ..  both laptops have the same specs suddenly i have this error showing when i run my application

i am using the xtraReport Extinsion to do some reports in the application .. what might be the problem ..

i have searched for it and found nothing some people told me its because of silverlight 5, but its installed also in my other laptop and everything is working fine

can any one help me please ??

[image: Could Not Load File Error]

Comment: Is DevExpress Library installed on both systems?

Comment: Yes and both the same version

Answer (score 1):

Please, try [answer for similar question](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q340244.aspx) from the [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center).